# In the Trinity doctrine, did the human nature of the Son die on the cross?

Tags: trinity, incarnation

In the Trinity doctrine, the incarnated Son of God has both a human and a divine nature. But He died on the cross. I understand the Trinity doctrine to say that His divine nature cannot die. But does that mean that His human nature died? To state this differently, in the Trinity doctrine, does He still have a human nature? Is He still a human being? Or is He now only a divine Being?

Comment: This question might be better placed on Christianity SX.

Comment: See John 21:27-29, Luke 24:38, 39, 41 - Jesus remained human as well as divine.

Comment: Yes. One's "nature" doesn't die... one's body does. This is true of both Jesus and the rest of us.

Comment: This question has been adequately and expertly dealt with on SE-Christianity, in a number of questions, all dealing with different aspects of he same subject.

Answer (score 1):

Not the entire human nature, for the Uncreated Eternal Logos’ created human soul did not co-die with His biological human created body, but He commended this soul to the Father (Luke 23:46), a living soul to the living God, just like Stephen did (Acts 7:59).

Moreover, with the same created soul, until His body lay dead in the tomb, the Logos descended to Hades and gladdened there souls of men deceased in ancient times, as ancient as Noah’s deluge, which means all generations before and after Noah (1 Peter 3:19). Thus, even before the general resurrection in bodies, which will happen at the End of Times, the souls of all men are living and conscious, no matter whatever illogical and unbiblical arrows the Jehova-witnessers may hurl around in order to push their heretical doctrine of soul’s co-death with body.

Thus, not entirety of His human nature died, just like when we die, our entire human nature does not die, because our personalities, sometimes traditionally called souls, remain alive and conscious and go to the presence of God in unspeakable bliss, if we deserve it.

Comment: @Down-voter Hey, my old friend! Not the answer you expected? Again you were so pricked in heart by my rightful answer that, forgetting all shame, still could not withstand the ignoble act of cowardly down-voting with no substantiation? What to say? For you I am ashamed with a Spanish shame!

Comment: "He commended this soul to the Father (Luke 23:46), a living soul to the living God, just like Stephen did (Acts 7:59)." It's a shame when answers are down-voted but with no reason given.

Comment: @Lesley Thanks, Lesley!